# Fast way to add countries as a custom taxonomy term?

Tags: customization, taxonomy, terms

Is there a quick way to add a list of countries as terms to a custom taxonomy called "Country"?

Is there an existing import file, SQL script ect...

I don't want to be there all day manually adding them.

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Get them here: [List of countries in YAML, CSV and TXT format (github)](https://gist.github.com/396531)

Comment: This is a *content* question, and is off-topic. Getting a list of country names really has nothing directly to do with WordPress.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this. Note that I found this country array online and cannot vouch for it's accuracy. Also, I've set the taxonomy to the "country" taxonomy. Change all instances of that if it does not match your specific taxonomy name. You can add this to your functions.php file in your current theme. Reload WordPress and it should add them. Once they are added, delete this code. I did put a check in there to make sure they aren't added twice.

```
add_action('init', 'add_countries', 100);

function add_countries()
{
    $country_array = array(
        'AF'=>'AFGHANISTAN',
        'AL'=>'ALBANIA',
        'DZ'=>'ALGERIA',
        'AS'=>'AMERICAN SAMOA',
        'AD'=>'ANDORRA',
        'AO'=>'ANGOLA',
        'AI'=>'ANGUILLA',
        'AQ'=>'ANTARCTICA',
        'AG'=>'ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA',
        'AR'=>'ARGENTINA',
        'AM'=>'ARMENIA',
        'AW'=>'ARUBA',
        'AU'=>'AUSTRALIA',
        'AT'=>'AUSTRIA',
        'AZ'=>'AZERBAIJAN',
        'BS'=>'BAHAMAS',
        'BH'=>'BAHRAIN',
        'BD'=>'BANGLADESH',
        'BB'=>'BARBADOS',
        'BY'=>'BELARUS',
        'BE'=>'BELGIUM',
        'BZ'=>'BELIZE',
        'BJ'=>'BENIN',
        'BM'=>'BERMUDA',
        'BT'=>'BHUTAN',
        'BO'=>'BOLIVIA',
        'BA'=>'BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA',
        'BW'=>'BOTSWANA',
        'BV'=>'BOUVET ISLAND',
        'BR'=>'BRAZIL',
        'IO'=>'BRITISH INDIAN OCEAN TERRITORY',
        'BN'=>'BRUNEI DARUSSALAM',
        'BG'=>'BULGARIA',
        'BF'=>'BURKINA FASO',
        'BI'=>'BURUNDI',
        'KH'=>'CAMBODIA',
        'CM'=>'CAMEROON',
        'CA'=>'CANADA',
        'CV'=>'CAPE VERDE',
        'KY'=>'CAYMAN ISLANDS',
        'CF'=>'CENTRAL AFRICAN REPUBLIC',
        'TD'=>'CHAD',
        'CL'=>'CHILE',
        'CN'=>'CHINA',
        'CX'=>'CHRISTMAS ISLAND',
        'CC'=>'COCOS (KEELING) ISLANDS',
        'CO'=>'COLOMBIA',
        'KM'=>'COMOROS',
        'CG'=>'CONGO',
        'CD'=>'CONGO, THE DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE',
        'CK'=>'COOK ISLANDS',
        'CR'=>'COSTA RICA',
        'CI'=>'COTE D IVOIRE',
        'HR'=>'CROATIA',
        'CU'=>'CUBA',
        'CY'=>'CYPRUS',
        'CZ'=>'CZECH REPUBLIC',
        'DK'=>'DENMARK',
        'DJ'=>'DJIBOUTI',
        'DM'=>'DOMINICA',
        'DO'=>'DOMINICAN REPUBLIC',
        'TP'=>'EAST TIMOR',
        'EC'=>'ECUADOR',
        'EG'=>'EGYPT',
        'SV'=>'EL SALVADOR',
        'GQ'=>'EQUATORIAL GUINEA',
        'ER'=>'ERITREA',
        'EE'=>'ESTONIA',
        'ET'=>'ETHIOPIA',
        'FK'=>'FALKLAND ISLANDS (MALVINAS)',
        'FO'=>'FAROE ISLANDS',
        'FJ'=>'FIJI',
        'FI'=>'FINLAND',
        'FR'=>'FRANCE',
        'GF'=>'FRENCH GUIANA',
        'PF'=>'FRENCH POLYNESIA',
        'TF'=>'FRENCH SOUTHERN TERRITORIES',
        'GA'=>'GABON',
        'GM'=>'GAMBIA',
        'GE'=>'GEORGIA',
        'DE'=>'GERMANY',
        'GH'=>'GHANA',
        'GI'=>'GIBRALTAR',
        'GR'=>'GREECE',
        'GL'=>'GREENLAND',
        'GD'=>'GRENADA',
        'GP'=>'GUADELOUPE',
        'GU'=>'GUAM',
        'GT'=>'GUATEMALA',
        'GN'=>'GUINEA',
        'GW'=>'GUINEA-BISSAU',
        'GY'=>'GUYANA',
        'HT'=>'HAITI',
        'HM'=>'HEARD ISLAND AND MCDONALD ISLANDS',
        'VA'=>'HOLY SEE (VATICAN CITY STATE)',
        'HN'=>'HONDURAS',
        'HK'=>'HONG KONG',
        'HU'=>'HUNGARY',
        'IS'=>'ICELAND',
        'IN'=>'INDIA',
        'ID'=>'INDONESIA',
        'IR'=>'IRAN, ISLAMIC REPUBLIC OF',
        'IQ'=>'IRAQ',
        'IE'=>'IRELAND',
        'IL'=>'ISRAEL',
        'IT'=>'ITALY',
        'JM'=>'JAMAICA',
        'JP'=>'JAPAN',
        'JO'=>'JORDAN',
        'KZ'=>'KAZAKSTAN',
        'KE'=>'KENYA',
        'KI'=>'KIRIBATI',
        'KP'=>'KOREA DEMOCRATIC PEOPLES REPUBLIC OF',
        'KR'=>'KOREA REPUBLIC OF',
        'KW'=>'KUWAIT',
        'KG'=>'KYRGYZSTAN',
        'LA'=>'LAO PEOPLES DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC',
        'LV'=>'LATVIA',
        'LB'=>'LEBANON',
        'LS'=>'LESOTHO',
        'LR'=>'LIBERIA',
        'LY'=>'LIBYAN ARAB JAMAHIRIYA',
        'LI'=>'LIECHTENSTEIN',
        'LT'=>'LITHUANIA',
        'LU'=>'LUXEMBOURG',
        'MO'=>'MACAU',
        'MK'=>'MACEDONIA, THE FORMER YUGOSLAV REPUBLIC OF',
        'MG'=>'MADAGASCAR',
        'MW'=>'MALAWI',
        'MY'=>'MALAYSIA',
        'MV'=>'MALDIVES',
        'ML'=>'MALI',
        'MT'=>'MALTA',
        'MH'=>'MARSHALL ISLANDS',
        'MQ'=>'MARTINIQUE',
        'MR'=>'MAURITANIA',
        'MU'=>'MAURITIUS',
        'YT'=>'MAYOTTE',
        'MX'=>'MEXICO',
        'FM'=>'MICRONESIA, FEDERATED STATES OF',
        'MD'=>'MOLDOVA, REPUBLIC OF',
        'MC'=>'MONACO',
        'MN'=>'MONGOLIA',
        'MS'=>'MONTSERRAT',
        'MA'=>'MOROCCO',
        'MZ'=>'MOZAMBIQUE',
        'MM'=>'MYANMAR',
        'NA'=>'NAMIBIA',
        'NR'=>'NAURU',
        'NP'=>'NEPAL',
        'NL'=>'NETHERLANDS',
        'AN'=>'NETHERLANDS ANTILLES',
        'NC'=>'NEW CALEDONIA',
        'NZ'=>'NEW ZEALAND',
        'NI'=>'NICARAGUA',
        'NE'=>'NIGER',
        'NG'=>'NIGERIA',
        'NU'=>'NIUE',
        'NF'=>'NORFOLK ISLAND',
        'MP'=>'NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS',
        'NO'=>'NORWAY',
        'OM'=>'OMAN',
        'PK'=>'PAKISTAN',
        'PW'=>'PALAU',
        'PS'=>'PALESTINIAN TERRITORY, OCCUPIED',
        'PA'=>'PANAMA',
        'PG'=>'PAPUA NEW GUINEA',
        'PY'=>'PARAGUAY',
        'PE'=>'PERU',
        'PH'=>'PHILIPPINES',
        'PN'=>'PITCAIRN',
        'PL'=>'POLAND',
        'PT'=>'PORTUGAL',
        'PR'=>'PUERTO RICO',
        'QA'=>'QATAR',
        'RE'=>'REUNION',
        'RO'=>'ROMANIA',
        'RU'=>'RUSSIAN FEDERATION',
        'RW'=>'RWANDA',
        'SH'=>'SAINT HELENA',
        'KN'=>'SAINT KITTS AND NEVIS',
        'LC'=>'SAINT LUCIA',
        'PM'=>'SAINT PIERRE AND MIQUELON',
        'VC'=>'SAINT VINCENT AND THE GRENADINES',
        'WS'=>'SAMOA',
        'SM'=>'SAN MARINO',
        'ST'=>'SAO TOME AND PRINCIPE',
        'SA'=>'SAUDI ARABIA',
        'SN'=>'SENEGAL',
        'SC'=>'SEYCHELLES',
        'SL'=>'SIERRA LEONE',
        'SG'=>'SINGAPORE',
        'SK'=>'SLOVAKIA',
        'SI'=>'SLOVENIA',
        'SB'=>'SOLOMON ISLANDS',
        'SO'=>'SOMALIA',
        'ZA'=>'SOUTH AFRICA',
        'GS'=>'SOUTH GEORGIA AND THE SOUTH SANDWICH ISLANDS',
        'ES'=>'SPAIN',
        'LK'=>'SRI LANKA',
        'SD'=>'SUDAN',
        'SR'=>'SURINAME',
        'SJ'=>'SVALBARD AND JAN MAYEN',
        'SZ'=>'SWAZILAND',
        'SE'=>'SWEDEN',
        'CH'=>'SWITZERLAND',
        'SY'=>'SYRIAN ARAB REPUBLIC',
        'TW'=>'TAIWAN, PROVINCE OF CHINA',
        'TJ'=>'TAJIKISTAN',
        'TZ'=>'TANZANIA, UNITED REPUBLIC OF',
        'TH'=>'THAILAND',
        'TG'=>'TOGO',
        'TK'=>'TOKELAU',
        'TO'=>'TONGA',
        'TT'=>'TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO',
        'TN'=>'TUNISIA',
        'TR'=>'TURKEY',
        'TM'=>'TURKMENISTAN',
        'TC'=>'TURKS AND CAICOS ISLANDS',
        'TV'=>'TUVALU',
        'UG'=>'UGANDA',
        'UA'=>'UKRAINE',
        'AE'=>'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES',
        'GB'=>'UNITED KINGDOM',
        'US'=>'UNITED STATES',
        'UM'=>'UNITED STATES MINOR OUTLYING ISLANDS',
        'UY'=>'URUGUAY',
        'UZ'=>'UZBEKISTAN',
        'VU'=>'VANUATU',
        'VE'=>'VENEZUELA',
        'VN'=>'VIET NAM',
        'VG'=>'VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH',
        'VI'=>'VIRGIN ISLANDS, U.S.',
        'WF'=>'WALLIS AND FUTUNA',
        'EH'=>'WESTERN SAHARA',
        'YE'=>'YEMEN',
        'YU'=>'YUGOSLAVIA',
        'ZM'=>'ZAMBIA',
        'ZW'=>'ZIMBABWE',
    );

    // Loop through array and insert terms
    foreach($country_array as $abbr => $name)
    {
        if(!get_term_by('name', ucwords(strtolower($name)), 'country'))
            wp_insert_term(ucwords(strtolower($name)), 'country');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I put this code?

Comment: Put it in your functions.php file of your current theme. Run it once then remove it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, checked the name and it is country... placed the code in my functions file and refreshed nada

Comment: The custom taxonomy is attached to a custom post type called "story", would that effect things?

Comment: I edited the original post. Try it. I did something foolish. I should run the code on 'init' otherwise your taxonomy is probably not yet defined and it won't add terms to an undefined taxonomy.

Comment: That did the trick! Many thanks, learning lots through stack exchange.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you should **accept** it, by clicking the checkmark beneath the question up/down vote arrows.

Answer (score 2):

@tollmanz did a nice job, this way works. I have now just updated it with the more actual list of countries and in lowercase.

```
add_action('init', 'add_countries', 100);

function add_countries()
{
    $country_array = array (
            'AF' => 'Afghanistan',
            'AX' => 'Åland Islands',
            'AL' => 'Albania',
            'DZ' => 'Algeria',
            'AS' => 'American Samoa',
            'AD' => 'Andorra',
            'AO' => 'Angola',
            'AI' => 'Anguilla',
            'AQ' => 'Antarctica',
            'AG' => 'Antigua & Barbuda',
            'AR' => 'Argentina',
            'AM' => 'Armenia',
            'AW' => 'Aruba',
            'AU' => 'Australia',
            'AT' => 'Austria',
            'AZ' => 'Azerbaijan',
            'BS' => 'Bahamas',
            'BH' => 'Bahrain',
            'BD' => 'Bangladesh',
            'BB' => 'Barbados',
            'BY' => 'Belarus',
            'BE' => 'Belgium',
            'BZ' => 'Belize',
            'BJ' => 'Benin',
            'BM' => 'Bermuda',
            'BT' => 'Bhutan',
            'BO' => 'Bolivia',
            'BA' => 'Bosnia & Herzegovina',
            'BW' => 'Botswana',
            'BV' => 'Bouvet Island',
            'BR' => 'Brazil',
            'IO' => 'British Indian Ocean Territory',
            'VG' => 'British Virgin Islands',
            'BN' => 'Brunei',
            'BG' => 'Bulgaria',
            'BF' => 'Burkina Faso',
            'BI' => 'Burundi',
            'KH' => 'Cambodia',
            'CM' => 'Cameroon',
            'CA' => 'Canada',
            'CV' => 'Cape Verde',
            'BQ' => 'Caribbean Netherlands',
            'KY' => 'Cayman Islands',
            'CF' => 'Central African Republic',
            'TD' => 'Chad',
            'CL' => 'Chile',
            'CN' => 'China',
            'CX' => 'Christmas Island',
            'CC' => 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands',
            'CO' => 'Colombia',
            'KM' => 'Comoros',
            'CG' => 'Congo - Brazzaville',
            'CD' => 'Congo - Kinshasa',
            'CK' => 'Cook Islands',
            'CR' => 'Costa Rica',
            'CI' => 'Côte d’Ivoire',
            'HR' => 'Croatia',
            'CU' => 'Cuba',
            'CW' => 'Curaçao',
            'CY' => 'Cyprus',
            'CZ' => 'Czechia',
            'DK' => 'Denmark',
            'DJ' => 'Djibouti',
            'DM' => 'Dominica',
            'DO' => 'Dominican Republic',
            'EC' => 'Ecuador',
            'EG' => 'Egypt',
            'SV' => 'El Salvador',
            'GQ' => 'Equatorial Guinea',
            'ER' => 'Eritrea',
            'EE' => 'Estonia',
            'SZ' => 'Eswatini',
            'ET' => 'Ethiopia',
            'FK' => 'Falkland Islands',
            'FO' => 'Faroe Islands',
            'FJ' => 'Fiji',
            'FI' => 'Finland',
            'FR' => 'France',
            'GF' => 'French Guiana',
            'PF' => 'French Polynesia',
            'TF' => 'French Southern Territories',
            'GA' => 'Gabon',
            'GM' => 'Gambia',
            'GE' => 'Georgia',
            'DE' => 'Germany',
            'GH' => 'Ghana',
            'GI' => 'Gibraltar',
            'GR' => 'Greece',
            'GL' => 'Greenland',
            'GD' => 'Grenada',
            'GP' => 'Guadeloupe',
            'GU' => 'Guam',
            'GT' => 'Guatemala',
            'GG' => 'Guernsey',
            'GN' => 'Guinea',
            'GW' => 'Guinea-Bissau',
            'GY' => 'Guyana',
            'HT' => 'Haiti',
            'HM' => 'Heard & McDonald Islands',
            'HN' => 'Honduras',
            'HK' => 'Hong Kong SAR China',
            'HU' => 'Hungary',
            'IS' => 'Iceland',
            'IN' => 'India',
            'ID' => 'Indonesia',
            'IR' => 'Iran',
            'IQ' => 'Iraq',
            'IE' => 'Ireland',
            'IM' => 'Isle of Man',
            'IL' => 'Israel',
            'IT' => 'Italy',
            'JM' => 'Jamaica',
            'JP' => 'Japan',
            'JE' => 'Jersey',
            'JO' => 'Jordan',
            'KZ' => 'Kazakhstan',
            'KE' => 'Kenya',
            'KI' => 'Kiribati',
            'KW' => 'Kuwait',
            'KG' => 'Kyrgyzstan',
            'LA' => 'Laos',
            'LV' => 'Latvia',
            'LB' => 'Lebanon',
            'LS' => 'Lesotho',
            'LR' => 'Liberia',
            'LY' => 'Libya',
            'LI' => 'Liechtenstein',
            'LT' => 'Lithuania',
            'LU' => 'Luxembourg',
            'MO' => 'Macao SAR China',
            'MG' => 'Madagascar',
            'MW' => 'Malawi',
            'MY' => 'Malaysia',
            'MV' => 'Maldives',
            'ML' => 'Mali',
            'MT' => 'Malta',
            'MH' => 'Marshall Islands',
            'MQ' => 'Martinique',
            'MR' => 'Mauritania',
            'MU' => 'Mauritius',
            'YT' => 'Mayotte',
            'MX' => 'Mexico',
            'FM' => 'Micronesia',
            'MD' => 'Moldova',
            'MC' => 'Monaco',
            'MN' => 'Mongolia',
            'ME' => 'Montenegro',
            'MS' => 'Montserrat',
            'MA' => 'Morocco',
            'MZ' => 'Mozambique',
            'MM' => 'Myanmar (Burma)',
            'NA' => 'Namibia',
            'NR' => 'Nauru',
            'NP' => 'Nepal',
            'NL' => 'Netherlands',
            'NC' => 'New Caledonia',
            'NZ' => 'New Zealand',
            'NI' => 'Nicaragua',
            'NE' => 'Niger',
            'NG' => 'Nigeria',
            'NU' => 'Niue',
            'NF' => 'Norfolk Island',
            'KP' => 'North Korea',
            'MK' => 'North Macedonia',
            'MP' => 'Northern Mariana Islands',
            'NO' => 'Norway',
            'OM' => 'Oman',
            'PK' => 'Pakistan',
            'PW' => 'Palau',
            'PS' => 'Palestinian Territories',
            'PA' => 'Panama',
            'PG' => 'Papua New Guinea',
            'PY' => 'Paraguay',
            'PE' => 'Peru',
            'PH' => 'Philippines',
            'PN' => 'Pitcairn Islands',
            'PL' => 'Poland',
            'PT' => 'Portugal',
            'PR' => 'Puerto Rico',
            'QA' => 'Qatar',
            'RE' => 'Réunion',
            'RO' => 'Romania',
            'RU' => 'Russia',
            'RW' => 'Rwanda',
            'WS' => 'Samoa',
            'SM' => 'San Marino',
            'ST' => 'São Tomé & Príncipe',
            'SA' => 'Saudi Arabia',
            'SN' => 'Senegal',
            'RS' => 'Serbia',
            'SC' => 'Seychelles',
            'SL' => 'Sierra Leone',
            'SG' => 'Singapore',
            'SX' => 'Sint Maarten',
            'SK' => 'Slovakia',
            'SI' => 'Slovenia',
            'SB' => 'Solomon Islands',
            'SO' => 'Somalia',
            'ZA' => 'South Africa',
            'GS' => 'South Georgia & South Sandwich Islands',
            'KR' => 'South Korea',
            'SS' => 'South Sudan',
            'ES' => 'Spain',
            'LK' => 'Sri Lanka',
            'BL' => 'St. Barthélemy',
            'SH' => 'St. Helena',
            'KN' => 'St. Kitts & Nevis',
            'LC' => 'St. Lucia',
            'MF' => 'St. Martin',
            'PM' => 'St. Pierre & Miquelon',
            'VC' => 'St. Vincent & Grenadines',
            'SD' => 'Sudan',
            'SR' => 'Suriname',
            'SJ' => 'Svalbard & Jan Mayen',
            'SE' => 'Sweden',
            'CH' => 'Switzerland',
            'SY' => 'Syria',
            'TW' => 'Taiwan',
            'TJ' => 'Tajikistan',
            'TZ' => 'Tanzania',
            'TH' => 'Thailand',
            'TL' => 'Timor-Leste',
            'TG' => 'Togo',
            'TK' => 'Tokelau',
            'TO' => 'Tonga',
            'TT' => 'Trinidad & Tobago',
            'TN' => 'Tunisia',
            'TR' => 'Turkey',
            'TM' => 'Turkmenistan',
            'TC' => 'Turks & Caicos Islands',
            'TV' => 'Tuvalu',
            'UM' => 'U.S. Outlying Islands',
            'VI' => 'U.S. Virgin Islands',
            'UG' => 'Uganda',
            'UA' => 'Ukraine',
            'AE' => 'United Arab Emirates',
            'GB' => 'United Kingdom',
            'US' => 'United States',
            'UY' => 'Uruguay',
            'UZ' => 'Uzbekistan',
            'VU' => 'Vanuatu',
            'VA' => 'Vatican City',
            'VE' => 'Venezuela',
            'VN' => 'Vietnam',
            'WF' => 'Wallis & Futuna',
            'EH' => 'Western Sahara',
            'YE' => 'Yemen',
            'ZM' => 'Zambia',
            'ZW' => 'Zimbabwe',
        );

    // Loop through array and insert terms
    foreach($country_array as $abbr => $name)
    {
        if(!get_term_by('name', ucwords(strtolower($name)), 'country'))
            wp_insert_term(ucwords(strtolower($name)), 'country');
    }
}
```

Source of countries: https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list

Answer (score 2):

This is for Algerian wilayas & communes, for the full code check this repo: https://github.com/ilyesrd/Insert-Wilayas-Communes-to-custom-taxonomy-in-wordpress

```
add_action('init', 'add_wilayas_and_communes', 100);

function add_wilayas_and_communes()
{
    $communes = array(
        // Take a look to this repo: https://github.com/ilyesrd/Insert-Wilayas-Communes-to-custom-taxonomy-in-wordpress
    );

    $wilayas = array(
        "1" => "Adrar",
        "2" => "Chlef",
        "3" => "Laghouat",
        "4" => "Oum El Bouaghi",
        "5" => "Batna",
        "6" => "Béjaïa",
        "7" => "Biskra",
        "8" => "Béchar",
        "9" => "Blida",
        "10" => "Bouira",
        "11" => "Tamanrasset",
        "12" => "Tébessa",
        "13" => "Tlemcen",
        "14" => "Tiaret",
        "15" => "Tizi Ouzou",
        "16" => "Alger",
        "17" => "Djelfa",
        "18" => "Jijel",
        "19" => "Sétif",
        "20" => "Saïda",
        "21" => "Skikda",
        "22" => "Sidi Bel Abbès",
        "23" => "Annaba",
        "24" => "Guelma",
        "25" => "Constantine",
        "26" => "Médéa",
        "27" => "Mostaganem",
        "28" => "M'Sila",
        "29" => "Mascara",
        "30" => "Ouargla",
        "31" => "Oran",
        "32" => "El Bayadh",
        "33" => "Illizi",
        "34" => "Bordj Bou Arreridj",
        "35" => "Boumerdès",
        "36" => "El Tarf",
        "37" => "Tindouf",
        "38" => "Tissemsilt",
        "39" => "El Oued",
        "40" => "Khenchela",
        "41" => "Souk Ahras",
        "42" => "Tipaza",
        "43" => "Mila",
        "44" => "Aïn Defla",
        "45" => "Naâma",
        "46" => "Aïn Témouchent",
        "47" => "Ghardaïa",
        "48" => "Relizane",
    );

    // Loop through array and insert terms
    foreach($wilayas as $abbr => $name)
    {
        if(!get_term_by('name', ucwords(strtolower($name)), 'wilayas'))
            wp_insert_term(ucwords(strtolower($name)), 'wilayas');
    }
    
    // Loop through array and insert terms
    foreach($communes as $abbr => $name)
    {
        if(!get_term_by('name', ucwords(strtolower($name)), 'communes'))
            wp_insert_term(ucwords(strtolower($name)), 'communes');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own script to import them using [wp_insert_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term).

Comment: That is still going to involve a lot of manual typing :)

Comment: @Dan you're gonna LOVE [foreach](http://cz2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop ;)

Answer (score -3):

I just want to add that if you see a 404 page after you add this taxonomy for a post type, then you simply put `flush_rewrite_rules();` in the register taxonomy section.

For example:

```
register_taxonomy( 'country', array( 'job' ), $args );  
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Comment: Never do that. That is a really expensive functions which will rebuild your permalinks on **every** page load. This slows your page down dramatically which is really bad for SEO and also hits your db hard. Please check the codex on how to properly use this function